# Django ListView display items with for loop. Mirror every 2nd

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a django product overview page.

I display categories with a listview. I use a Bootstrap grid with two columns to display the categories as follows:

```
picture | Info
```

I now ant every 2nd column to be mirrored so the end resukt will be like this:

```
Picture | Info
Info | Picture
Picture | Info
```

How do I run a loop to make this work? My code looks like this:

```
<div class='container'>

    {% for category in categories  %}

<!-- Check is subcategory exists. if not, filter on category. If it does exist filter on subcategory -->
    {% if category.sub_category is Null %}

        <a href="{% url 'academy:brandByCat_list' category.category_name %}">
            <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                <div class='col-md item-img'>
                    <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md">
                    <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.category_name}}</h1>
                    <p>{{category.category_info}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>



        {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'academy:brandBySubCat_list' category.sub_category %}">
            <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                <div class='col-md item-img'>
                    <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md">
                    <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.sub_category}}</h1>
                    <p>{{category.category_info}}</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </a>

    {% endif %}


    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

By using a nested `forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2'` i managed to make it work.

```
        {% for category in categories  %}

        <!-- Check is subcategory exists. if not, filter on category. If it does exist filter on subcategory -->
        {% if category.sub_category is Null %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2' %}
                    <a href="{% url 'academy:brandByCat_list' category.category_name %}">
                        <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                            <div class='col-md item-img'>
                                <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md">
                                <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.category_name}}</h1>
                                <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </a>
                
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'academy:brandByCat_list' category.category_name %}">
                        <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                            <div class="col-md">
                                <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.category_name}}</h1>
                                <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}
                            </div>

                            <div class='col-md item-img'>
                                <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </a>
            {% endif %}

            {% else %}

            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:'2' %}
                <a href="{% url 'academy:brandBySubCat_list' category.sub_category %}">
                    <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                        <div class='col-md item-img'>
                            <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md">
                            <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.sub_category}}</h1>
                            <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}</p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>

                {% else %}

                <a href="{% url 'academy:brandBySubCat_list' category.sub_category %}">
                    <div class="row py-3 item-display">

                        <div class="col-md">
                            <h1 class='py-3'>{{category.sub_category}}</h1>
                            <p>{{category.category_info | linebreaks}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-md item-img'>
                            <img src= {{category.category_picture.url}} class="img-fluid category-picture">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </a>
            {% endif %}

        {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}
```